# The operator '>=' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. flutter null safety

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code

```
 if (myCart?.cart?.cartDetails != null &&
    myCart?.cart?.cartDetails!
            .indexWhere((element) => element.productId == productId)  >=
        0) {
  return true;
}
```

this code gets an error in ">=" part saying it can be null.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexWhere` can return null in your case and the `>=` operator cannot be used with a null value. Try the following code:

```dart
final index = myCart?.cart?.cartDetails
    ?.indexWhere((element) => element.productId == productId);

if (index != null && index >= 0) {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because element.productId can be null.
can you try element.productId! == productId or element.productId? == productId